# concatenate integer 0 with other integers in python3

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation

I'm able to concatenate below 2 integers using below code:

```
x = 1
y = 2
print(int(str(x) + str(y)))
```

**output:**

```
12
```

but in below case, it's not working:

```
x = 0
y = 2
print(int(str(x) + str(y)))
```

**output:**

```
2
```

**Expected output:**

```
02
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int(x)` is used to convert its argument 'x' to an integer. So, when you do `str(x)+str(y)`, you get '02', a string data. But when this is passed as an argument to `int()`, it becomes 2, because, well 0 has no value when placed before a number (before the decimal).

To get 02, just leave it at `str(x)+str(y)`.